# Exec doesn't work with functions and variables

Tags: python, exec

I am making a plugin system that works with .py files. When I do exec() with that plugin (.py file) and it has a function or variable it gives a NameError.

> NameError: name 'editor_nf' is not defined

I've already googled it but I didn't find anything that helps me.

I only did:

```py
plugin = open("plugin.py","r").read()
exec(plugin)
```

and the plugin.py file is:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def editor_nf():
    enf = tk.Tk()
    enf.title("New file")
    enf.config(bg="white")
    enf.geometry("500x500")

    enf.mainloop()

def editor():
    editor = tk.Tk()
    editor.title("Website Editor")
    editor.config(bg="white")
    editor.geometry("1400x700")

    editor_nf_btn = tk.Button(editor,text="New file",bg="gray",fg="black",font="Arial",command=editor_nf)
    editor_nf_btn.grid(row=0,column=0)

    editor.mainloop()

editor()
```

So I want it to work with functions so people can create WORKING functions.

I don't want it to show:

> NameError: name 'editor_nf' is not defined

dcg answered and it helped but then I converted it to exe and I got this
[image: dcg answered and it helped but then I converted it to exe and I got this]

Comment: Is there a problem to do `import plugin`? Also, note you can dynamically do imports like `__import__(<module_path>)`.

Comment: @dcg no cause I want everyone to create plugins and upload them, wich means if I do it like that I need to update it everytime, and if anytime in the future 100k people make plugins, that wont't work.

Comment: _it gives a NameError_ Show us the full error message.

Comment: @JohnGordon edited

Comment: @crowdzer I get it, you can use the function `__import__(<module_path>)` to import all plugins from a given location.

Comment: @dcg then I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\jesse\\Desktop\\FishCode\\FIDE/plugins/'

Comment: @crowdzer Try with the module name (`plugin`), there you're trying to import a folder.

Comment: Are you sure the `plugin.py` code is exactly as shown?  I tried this myself with a simplified example and it worked.

Comment: @dcg with `__import__("plugins")` it still doesnt work

Comment: @crowdzer As I see in your code it is not `plugins` but `plugin`

Comment: @dcg but the plugin is in the plugins folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give a simple example of what I was telling you in the comments. This is my folder structure:

```
/sample
   - plugins/
       - __init__.py # not necessary, but maybe you want to apply some logic 
                     # before importing the plugins
       - plugin1.py
       - plugin2.py
       - plugin3.py
   - __init__.py
   - test.py
```

Every plugin prints what plugins it is (e.g., `print('plugin 1')`). `test.py` is as follows:

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load plugins
    plugins = [p for p in os.listdir('plugins') if not p.startswith('_')]
    for p in plugins:
        __import__('plugins.'+p[:-3])
```

The output is:

```
plugin 1
plugin 2
plugin 3
```

Which means I successfully imported all those modules (plugins) by using `__import__`. Note that `__import__` returns a reference to the imported module, so you can store it for later manipulation. Hope it helps!

Comment: now look at my question, I editted it cause I don't know why that error is there and I have the folder still so please help

Answer (score 0):

I said I editted it with the error and stuff, but I fixed it on my own. Thanks for helping!